# QGIS Atlas not sorting values and grouping alike terms

Tags: qgis, qgis-atlas

I have set up the atlas to sort by the field of STREET. My issue is that I have multiple data points at different places but on the same street. I want the points located on the same street to be grouped into the same Data Driven Page, but the same street names are not being grouped together.

For example, my data is as follows:
[image]

I want all of the Bremner Blvd points to be on the same page in the atlas.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use another layer as the Atlas reference.

And make this layer from the main one as: the group by street name of your points. This will give you one entry by street name, and the relevant geographical extent.

You can do that with 'points to path' grouping by name, or virtual layer if you have SQL knowledge, there are probably other means.

Configure this layer not to be visible, from the Atlas settings